# How to return the values in a radgrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadGrid which is DataBound to a `IDictionary<string,string>` where there are 2 GridTemplateColumn containing a textbox, one showing the Key and the other showing the value. The user can the edit these values.

Is it possible to return a IDictionary which contains the all the values in the RadGrid (including the modified values) based on a button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible by extracting the values from the textboxes manually and updating the source IDictionary object accordingly. You may give it a spin to see how it works for you.